# Change scientific notation to decimal in swift

Tags: swift

I want to convert a float value from `1e-05` to `0.00001` in Swift.

I used the following extension:

```
extension Float {
    var avoidNotation: String {
      let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
      numberFormatter.allowsFloats = true
      numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
      numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
      return numberFormatter.number(from: "\(self)")!.stringValue
    }
}
```

But when I try to using with float value like `1e-05.avoidNotation` result its the same, insted of `0.00001`

Comment: Define "doesn't work". In what way exactly are you having an issue? Please update your question (don't post comments) with all relevant details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use Formatter's `string(for:)` method instead of getting the stringValue from the number resulting from your string interpolation:

```
extension Float {
    var avoidNotation: String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return numberFormatter.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}

Float(1e-05).avoidNotation    // "0.00001"
```

---

I would recommend also instead of creating a NumberFormatter every time you call that property extending Formatter and adding a static formatter. You can also extend FloatingPoint instead of Float so you extend all Floating Point types:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let avoidNotation: NumberFormatter = {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return numberFormatter
    }()
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var avoidNotation: String {
        return Formatter.avoidNotation.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}

Float(1e-05).avoidNotation   // "0.00001"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

Disable scientific notation:

```
let number = NSNumber(value: floatValue)
print(number.decimalValue)
```

**Extension:**

```
extension Float {

    func avoidNotation() -> String {
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        return "\(number.decimalValue)"
    }

}
```